# Hide some buttons

Tags: 8, webforms

I do not want to display the submissions button, the download button, and the customize button on the webform results tab for the user.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to hide menu item from the secondary tabs should be to alter the access callback of the menu item.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$item) {
  // This hides the sbmissions item. Others should work simillary.
  $item['node/%webform_menu/webform-results/submissions']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_webform_result_access';
}

function mymodule_webform_result_access($node, $account = NULL) {
  // You can put here any custom logic of your needs.
  return FALSE; 
}
```

Comment: The question is for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

To alter the tabs see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-alter-local-tasks-aka-tabs

You might want to consider creating a custom view using the [Webform Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views) module

Answer (score -1):

The simpler way is with css, `display:none` to the elements you want

Comment: This isn't secure. The permissions should be adjusted.